# Communication impossible between controllers

Tags: angularjs

**PRELIMINARIES**

I am developing a web app using angularjs. At some point, my main controller connects to a web service which sends data continuously. To capture and process the stream I am using (http://ajaxpatterns.org/HTTP_Streaming). Everything works like a charm. I would like to share these streaming data with another controller that will process and display them via a jquery chart library (not yet decided which one I gonna use but it is out of the scope of this question). To share these data I have followed this jsfiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/eshepelyuk/vhKfq/).

Please find below some relevant parts of my code.

Module, routes and service definitions:

```
var platform = angular.module('platform', ['ui']);

platform.config(['$routeProvider',function($routeProvider){
    $routeProvider.
        when('/home',{templateUrl:'partials/home.html',controller:PlatformCtrl}).
        when('/visu/:idVisu', {templateUrl: 'partials/visuTimeSeries.html',controller:VisuCtrl}).
        otherwise({redirectTo:'/home',templateUrl:'partials/home.html'})
}]);

platform.factory('mySharedService', function($rootScope) {
    return {
        broadcast: function(msg) {
            $rootScope.$broadcast('handleBroadcast', msg); 
        }
    };
});
```

PlatformCtrl definition:

```
function PlatformCtrl($scope,$http,$q,$routeParams, sharedService) {

  ...

  $scope.listDataVisu ={};

  ...

  $scope.listXhrReq[idVisu] = createXMLHttpRequest();
  $scope.listXhrReq[idVisu].open("get", urlConnect, true);
  $scope.listXhrReq[idVisu].onreadystatechange = function() {
     $scope.$apply(function () {
       var serverResponse = $scope.listXhrReq[idVisu].responseText;
       $scope.listDataVisu[idVisu] = serverResponse.split("\n");
       sharedService.broadcast($scope.listDataVisu);
    });
  };
  $scope.listXhrReq[idVisu].send(null);
  var w = window.open("#/visu/"+idVisu);

  $scope.$on('handleBroadcast', function(){
    console.log("handleBroadcast (platform)");
  });

}
```

VisuCtrl definition:

```
function VisuCtrl($scope,$routeParams,sharedService) {

    $scope.idVisu = $routeParams.idVisu;
    $scope.data = [];

    /* ***************************************
     *   LISTENER FOR THE HANDLEBROADCAST EVENT
     *****************************************/ 

    $scope.$on('handleBroadcast', function(event,data){
        console.log("handleBroadcast (visu)");
        $scope.data = data[$scope.idVisu];
    });


}
```

Injection:

```
PlatformCtrl.$inject = ['$scope','$http','$q','$routeParams','mySharedService'];
VisuCtrl.$inject = ['$scope','$routeParams','mySharedService'];
```

**PROBLEM DEFINITION**

When running this code, it looks like only the `PlatformCtrl` controller listens for the `handleBroadcast` event. Indeed, having a look to the console all what is displayed is only `handleBroadcast (platform)` every time new data arrive. I am very surprised because I have read in the official documentation that the `$broadcast` function

> dispatches an event name downwards to all child scopes (and their
>   children) notifying the registered ng.$rootScope.Scope#$on listeners.

Since all the scopes in a given app inherits from `$rootScope`, I do not get why the `$on` function in `VisuCtrl` is not launched every time new data are broadcasted.

Comment: So you are using the PlatformCtrl for /home and VisuCtrl at /visu/:idVisu but they still run at the same time? This is somewhat confusing :) Could you help me understand?

Comment: @Flek Exactly, the idea is to open a popup to display the streaming data using VisuCtrl. At the same time the PlatformCtrl will still run.

Comment: But are the two controllers really run within the same angular instance? I am asking because if I get it right you use window.open, so you open up a new browser window don't you?

Comment: @Flek Yes, I open a new window to display streaming data. Openning a new window will result in the creation of a second "independant" angular instance? If yes, that clearly explains why the two controllers cannot communicate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I think is that when you open a new browser window you are launching a new AngularJS instance. This way it's not possible that the two controllers are able to communicate via a service.

If you have problems with scopes communicating, you can inject the $rootScope and see whether all the scopes that should communicate are actually instanciated.

```
function VisuCtrl($scope, $routeParams, sharedService, $rootscope) {
    console.log($rootScope);
}
```

Comment: You're right and actually I came to the same conclusion. When the visuCtrl is on the same page than the PlatformCtrl, the two controllers can communicate. After some googling, it looks quite tricky to create a multi browser window application in javascript. Consequently, I will simulate this popup behavior using a modal window. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Your request flow comes out of the angular, therefore it would not be recognized until the next $digest phase (see how angular handles two-way binding via dirty matching). To get in to the angular world you need to use `$apply`:

```
  $scope.listXhrReq[idVisu].onreadystatechange = function() {
     $scope.$apply(function () {
       var serverResponse = $scope.listXhrReq[idVisu].responseText;
       $scope.listDataVisu[idVisu] = serverResponse.split("\n");
       sharedService.broadcast($scope.listDataVisu);
     });
  };
```

Comment: Reading your reply I though "How stupid I am!!" but actually even with your proposal the problem remains unchanged. To be certain I got what you meant, would have it been possible that your solution saves my day even if my bugged code correctly listens and reacts to the `handleBroadcast` event within the `PlatformCtrl` controller (console displays `handleBroadcast (platform)`)? Btw, I will edit my post to reflect your reply. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Could it be that your VisuCtrl hasn't been initialized yet, since you are using custom routing?
Is it still the same, when you navigate to `/visu/:idVisu`?

Comment: I am using the `ng-view` directive so my VisuCtrl has been initialized  (at least I think so). Btw thanks for your try.